# join two dataset on two columns sql domo

Tags: mysql, sql, join, domo

I am using MySQL with DOMO. I have two tables that I want to join on both columns. My data looks like the following:

The first table represents 2019 Revenue

```
Week        Name           2019 Revenue
1            Paul             576356
1            Nick             246564
2            Sam              426547265
2            Frank            5436
```

And the other table represents 2020 Revenue

```
Week        Name           2020 Revenue
1            Paul             554
1            Nick             200
2            Sam              400
2            Frank            500
```

I want the output be:

```
Week        Name           2019 Revenue         2020 Revenue
1            Paul             576356                  554
1            Nick             246564                  200
2            Sam              426547265               400
2            Frank            5436                    500
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
`Week`,
`Advertiser`,
`2019 Revenue`
from `2019` as a
left join `2020` as b
    on a.`Week` = b.`Week`
    and a.`Advertiser` = b.`Advertiser`
```

Error message: SQL constraint violated: Column 'Week' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: when coumn don't have a unique name you have to put the tabke anme infront of it, so that mysql can select the right one. in  your case it doesn't matter a is teh choice becaise you kleft join your  table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be obvious.  But the solution is that you get into the habit of *always* qualifying column names in queries:

```
SELECT a.Week, a.Advertiser, a.`2019 Revenue`, b.`2020 Revenue`
from `2019` a left join
     `2020` b
     on a.Week = b.Week and   
        a.Advertiser = b.Advertiser;
```

Comment: This doesn't return 2020 Revenue.

Comment: @Chique_Code . . . You just need to select it.

Comment: I have tried that yesterday, it didn't work. Now it ran perfectly. Thank you for your help. This solves my problem.